# Transition при задании height в процентах

Tags: position

Всем доброго времени суток! Подскажите как сделать растягивание блока по высоте с помощью анимации transition и задании высоты в процентах. При height в пикселях всё работает, как только ставлю % анимация исчезает появляется задержка(похоже что на то время которое длится анимация).  Заранее Спасибо!